# How to use "group by" query on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I tried to use "group by" query on AgensGraph.

But, there is no "group by" clause on CYPHER.

How can I use "group by" on query.

Answer (score 0):

CYPHER is distinct from SQL.

There is no explicit "GROUP BY" clause on grammar.

But, You can list extra column with aggregate function on return or with cluase.

```
# match (n:v) return n.x, sum(n.y);
 x | sum 
---+-----
 1 |   4
 2 |   9
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypher has no `Group by` clause, but with `AgensGraph` you can mix SQL and Cypher. You can write a Cypher-Query and insert it into another SQL-Query with `group_by`.

At the documentation is an example for such hybrid querys.
https://bitnine.net/documentations/developer-manual-en.html#hybrid-query